# Single backslash within a raw string - Regular Expressions

Tags: python

I am in the process of watching some Google classes on youtube and the current topic is regular expressions.  Came across the below code and there is a piece of the code and result that I could use some clarification on.

Why does the below return `c.l` instead of `not found`?  The pattern being searched is a raw string, in which I thought meant the backlash would be treated literally.

```
>>> import re

>>> def Find(pattern, text_string):
...     match = re.search(pattern, text_string)
...     if match:
...         print match.group()
...     else:
...         print 'not found'

>>> Find(r'c\.l', 'c.lled piiig   much better: zysdgs')
c.l
```

Comment: At first I thought it was because you are passing your raw string as an argument to your `Find` function, and maybe the `re.search` method needs the raw-ness of the string declared in its call, but after some testing that does not seem to be the case. It looks like the raw string is in fact treating "\." as an escaped period instead of two characters like it should. I want to hear a good explanation for this too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's using a regular expression. In regex a period stands for "match any character". However, the author of that code didn't want that functionality, (s)he wanted to literally match a period. So to indicate that, they used the backslash character to escape the period. So to the regex engine that expression means "match for c.l", which it does.

Comment: Take a look at the [Python re documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) (search for "raw"). When using `re` in Python, you can specify raw strings like `r'\n'` which will search for the backslash character followed by an "n", not a new line.

Comment: @Engineero But `r'\.'` and `'\.'` are the same thing, since '\.' is not a special character. '\.' tells regex to interpret '.' as a literal dot, not as 'any character'.

Comment: Oh, so because "." *is* special in the context of regex it would still be interpreted as "any character" in a raw string unless it is escaped? That makes sense now, thanks for the clarification!